# Jersey build with maven unbounded range JDK

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm building a web-service with `Jersey` using `maven`. When executing `mvn package` I'm receiving the following error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar': Invalid JDK version in profile 'javadoc-jdk8+': Unbounded range: [1.8 for project unknown:hk2-parent
  org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
1) com.rhcloud.susudev.tapapp:tapapp-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
2) org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:jar:2.22.1
```

pom.xml

```
<project>

...

    <build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Make this jar executable -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.rhcloud.susudev.tapapp.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Includes the runtime dependencies -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- One-Jar is in the googlecode repository -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using a JDK 8 and change `<jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>` to `<jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>` in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: What version of Maven and Jersey are you using?

Comment: https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-277

Answer (score 1):

open the 2.4.0-b31.pom and find the profile 'javadoc-jdk8+' and change the value to [1.8,)

Answer (score 0):

Use maven 3, I got the same error for maven 2

Answer (score 0):

upgraded jersey version to 2.25.1 solved the problem, 2.22.1 has a a bad manifest.